# Not sure what to put in callback function for routing with express and react front end

Tags: reactjs, express

I am new to react and I am trying to build an app where users can log in and out. I am using express for back-end purposes, when writing my routes for the register and login page I'm not sure what to put in the callback function of my get routes for register and login.

**Example**

```
    app.get("/register", (req, res)=>{
      // what do i put here?
     });
```

Usually i would just render an `ejs` template but im not sure what to do since react takes care of the rendering

Comment: This an overly broad question.  If you don't know what to do with registration then my personal suggestion would be to use an off-the-shelf product like Auth0.  Registration, authentication, and authorization are highly complex, easy to get wrong, and errors are disastrous.

Comment: Im using passport for the user auth, I'm wondering about the get routes not the post ones

Comment: Typically, React uses client side routing [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router) is a pretty popular choice. Client side routing means that express does not process your routes. express only serves the initial HTML and React does the rest, client side.  React is a client side framework. Outside of using express just to serve the initial HTML, it is typically used as an API so that React can grab any data you have stored.  If you are wanting to browse from page to page with React, you do not need express. [Example](https://github.com/oze4/react-navbar-search-with-routing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express passes `(req, res, next)` to every next argument after path in get or post. 
You can use it anyhow you want. 
Generally, req is what you get from the client, and with res.send(xxx) you respond to the client. 
I would recommend, try to build very simple server with

```
  console.log(req, res)
  res.send(200)
 })
```

And with some REST API tool (e.g. Advanced REST client for Chrome) try to send some requests and see what happens.

Then I strongly recommend to use www.passportjs.org, which will help you build your authentication and authorization part of your app.

Comment: alright thanks, I know how (req, res) works i was just confused that avout not having anything to return in some of my routes

Comment: If it is route of React router, than you don't define this route in Express. Route in Express is defined only for data fetching from server (e.g. REST API).